# Padding not preserved in printed document

Tags: css, firefox, media-queries

I am trying to create css styles for printing a document in Firefox.
I would like some content, placed inside a container, have equal spacing on top and bottom.

For that I've added a container having top and bottom padding and placed some content in it:

> ```
> <div class="container" style="padding: 1cm 0; box-decoration-break: clone">
>     ...some content ("div", "p" elements)
> </div>
> ```

Now, Firefox supports **box-decoration-break** css property (which allows to
repeat borders/padding/margin when container "hits" page break).

I am setting "**box-decoration-break: clone**" for the container and expecting the following behavior to happen:

```
Printed page 1:
------------
|          | <- correct spacing
|  content |
|  content |
|          | <- correct spacing
------------

Printed page 2:
------------
|          | <- correct spacing
|  content |
|  content |
|          | <- correct spacing
------------
```

In reality this is happening:

```
Printed page 1:
------------
|          | <- correct spacing
|  content |
|  content |
|  content | <- (!) incorrect spacing, content "ignores" parent padding
------------

Printed page 2:
------------
|          | <- correct spacing
|  content |
|          |
|          |
------------
```

The only way I could make the content respect parent element paddings was by setting 
all child elements of container to have "**display: contents**"
(which breaks all other styles and makes it look ugly)

I would like to get help on following questions:

1) What is the right way to create padding inside specific container in printed documents ?

2) Why my approach doesn't work ?

Thank you

Comment: This should be a Firefox bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1638491